# how to merge two dataframes when excel is containing merge cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge 2 dataframes in my Python code.

df1: 
[image]

df2 : 
[image]

I want the merged DataFrame as :
[image]

df1 and df2 are huge actually and can not be explained here. Please share some solution if possible

Comment: What are you trying to merge them by? For example, could the first dataset contain subtests the second one doesn't? Your merged example doesn't accurately display what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: When asking for Pandas help, it's always a good idea to think about how to provide a  [good, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) of your data - even if it's only a few data points - as it immediately allows people to work with it. When you supply data as images, you're much less likely to get a good answer.